# Setting uniforms in an unused shader affects output

Tags: opengl, shader, uniform

I'm learning OpenGL and I've stumbled upon an issue where I'm not sure why it happens. I have a shader (vertex + fragment) for which I set uniform variables. The shader is responsible for both drawing a skybox as well as the objects (it differentiates via the `uIsSkybox` uniform variable). Here's the code for each:

```
#version 330 core 

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoords;

out vec2 oObjTexCoords;
out vec3 oSkyboxTexCoords; 

uniform mat4 uModel;
uniform mat4 uView;
uniform mat4 uProjection;

uniform bool uIsSkybox;

void main()
{
    if(uIsSkybox)
    {
        mat4 mvp = uProjection * mat4(mat3(uView)) * uModel;
        oSkyboxTexCoords = aPos;
        vec4 pos = mvp * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
        gl_Position = pos.xyww;
    }
    else 
    {
        mat4 mvp = uProjection * uView * uModel;
        oObjTexCoords = aTexCoords;
        gl_Position = mvp * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    }
}
```

---

```
#version 330 core 

struct Material {
    sampler2D texture_diffuse;
    sampler2D texture_specular;
    float shininess;
};

in vec2 oObjTexCoords;
in vec3 oSkyboxTexCoords; 

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform Material material;
uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse1;
uniform samplerCube uSkyboxSampler;

uniform bool uIsSkybox;

void main() 
{
    if(uIsSkybox)
    {
        fragColor = texture(uSkyboxSampler, oSkyboxTexCoords);
    }
    else 
    {
//      fragColor = texture(texture_diffuse1, oObjTexCoords);
        fragColor = texture(material.texture_diffuse, oObjTexCoords);
    }

}
```

Here is the (desired) output:

[image: Correct output]

Before this I had a separate shader for the skybox. In code, I left the "setUniforms" code for this shader and only removed its usage (`glUseProgram`). I thought this would be enough since the shader is not being used anyway. However, it did affect my skybox and I'm not sure why.

```
model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
challengeShader.use();
challengeShader.setBool("uIsSkybox", true);
challengeShader.setMat4("uModel", model);
challengeShader.setMat4("uView", view);
challengeShader.setMat4("uProjection", projection);


//skyboxShader.use();
skyboxShader.setMat4("uModel", model);
skyboxShader.setMat4("uView", view);
skyboxShader.setMat4("uProjection", projection);
```

[image: Incorrect output]

Behind those setters are just calls to `glGetUniformLocation` and `glUniform...`. I've also made sure to confirm that both program IDs are not the same, and they are not. If I uncomment the setter calls of `skyboxShader` it works as desired. (It's really just the `view` matrix that causes this effect.) I also tried to give the uniforms separate names, but that makes no difference.

I'd like to know why this happens. I'll provide more information in case you need it.

PS: I had recently read that calls to `texture()` in the fragment shader should happen outside of branches. But in this case both argument types are different (`samplerCube` and `vec3` vs `sampler2D` and `vec2`), so I'm not sure if that's possible in this case.

Edit: Here's the code for `setMat4`:

```
void Shader::setMat4(const std::string& name, glm::mat4 value) const {
    int location = glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(value));
}
```

Comment: What does skyboxShader.setMat do? Does it just call glUniform? Did you notice that glUniform doesn't have the program number, so it affects the current program?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, as I said those are just calls to `gelGetUniformLocation` and `glUniform*`. `skyboxShader` and `challengeShader` both have different program IDs. I can post the code for that nonetheless.

Comment: `challengeShader` is being used (I have the call `challengeShader.use()` at the beginning of the loop). I'll add it to the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: That's also how I think about it, which is why it doesn't make sense to me. As far as I understand, setting a uniform for `skyboxShader` (program ID = 12) should not affect my `challengeShader` (program ID = 15). But it does. I'd say that perhaps the problem is somewhere else, but if I uncomment the setters for `skyboxShader` it works just fine.

Comment: Here's the full loop: https://pastebin.com/2MXSB66R

Comment: @Rabbid76 The code is there because originally I had two separate shaders (one for the skybox and one for the objects). So it was being used before. Then I decided to move everything into one shader. I removed the call to `skyboxShader.use()` to test if it works (I left the other calls because I thought they'd have no effect). I don't need `skyboxShader` anymore and eventually I'll delete it completely. I just didn't understand why setting uniforms for an unused program affected my used program.

Comment: Right now they're still there because I'm trying to figure out the cause of this. I could just remove them and go on, but I thought it might be a good idea to figure this out so that in the future I don't shoot myself in the leg (knowingly or unknowingly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge shader has its uniforms:

- Location 0 (probably): uModel
- Location 1 (probably): uView
- Location 2 (probably): uProjection
- Location 3 (probably): uIsSkybox
- ... and so on ...

And so does the skybox shader - let's say they're in a different order:

- Location 0 (for example): uProjection
- Location 1 (for example): uModel
- Location 2 (for example): uView
- ... and so on ...

When you do `skyboxShader.setMat4("uModel", model);` it calls `glGetUniformLocation(skyboxShader.ID, "uModel")` which tells you that uModel is location 1 in skyboxShader. Then, it calls `glUniformMatrix4fv(1, ...etc...)` which sets location 1 in the current shader, which is challengeShader, which is uView. See the problem?

`glUniformWhatever` always updates the uniforms in the currently used shader program. If you want to set uniforms in a different shader program, you have to use it first, or use [`glProgramUniformWhatever`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glProgramUniform.xhtml) instead (OpenGL 4.1+)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought that uniform locations will be unique per shader, hence the reason why we pass the program ID.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Forgive me if I misunderstood you, but what I had gotten from your answer was more or less what's written here in the last paragraph, but the answer I was looking for was more what's written in the first paragrah (-> why the uniforms of an unused program affect the used program).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Now that you mention it, yes, you kinda answered it before. I didn't understand before though because I didn't realize that the returned location of an unused program could be valid in the currently used program. Thanks for your efforts anyway, I've given you an upvote in another answer to make up for it (:

Comment: @Beko Never mind. I have to admit that this answer is the better one. However, similar questions have already been asked many times.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I thought so, but I kind of had trouble formulating the right question, so I didn't find any. I'll be more thorough next time. Cheers.